# In C programming, I'm trying to print my array in reverse using pointers but I can't seem to get it

Tags: c, unix, pointers, printf

This what I have right now it will not print the first or last number, I'm not sure why it's not

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int i, j;
  float ar[5] = {12.75, 18.34, 9.85, 23.78, 16.96}, br[5];
  float *ptrAr, *ptrBr;
  ptrAr = ar;
  ptrBr = &br[4];
  for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    *ptrBr = *ptrAr;
    ptrAr++;
    ptrBr--;
  }
  for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%5.2f\n", *ptrBr);
    ptrBr++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is a good task for a debugger, it is not simple to see an error in someone's code. Try using it and you may see the error easily. Btw, what is the result that is actually printed - first and last as 0?

Comment: @TomasPastircak: Debuggers might not find **Undefined Behavior** at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior, because `ptrBr` is set to `br-1`.
That means anything can happen, even the proverbial nasal demons:

```
ptrBr = &br[4];
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  *ptrBr = *ptrAr;
  ptrAr++;
  ptrBr--;
}
```

Change the loop to this:

```
ptrBr = br+5;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  *--ptrBr = *ptrAr++;
```

That will also fix your output, because `ptrBr == br` at this place now.

Answer (score 1):

reset your ptrBr before your print loop

ptrBr = br;

Answer (score 0):

Your program invokes undefined behavior as it access unallocated memory. In fact `ptrBr` points one element before the array `br` at the end of loop.
Change your `for` loop body to

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     printf("%5.2f\n", *++ptrBr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an additional  `ptrBr++;` after the 1st for loop. Since the last execution of your 1st `for` loop did an extra  `ptrBr--;`

```
                ptrBr++;
        for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                printf("%5.2f\n", *ptrBr);
                ptrBr++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```